# Cannot install spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

I am currently trying to install spacemacs on my Arch Linux. I am following the standard installation instructions that have been put up [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#default-installation).

Now, I am at the part where I need to launch emacs (Instruction no.3 of the Default Installation bit). This is the one after the one below:

```
git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d
```

But I get the error below when emacs comes up. What's wrong with the installation?

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
‘/home/sharand/.emacs.d/init.el’Warning (initialization): An error
occurred while loading ‘/home/sharand/.emacs.d/init.el’
```

What should I do?

### Debugging

I ran it with `--debug-init`

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Creating directory" "Permission denied" "/home/sharand/.emacs.d/.cache/")
  make-directory-internal("/home/sharand/.emacs.d/.cache/")
  make-directory("/home/sharand/.emacs.d/.cache/")
  (if (file-exists-p spacemacs-cache-directory) nil (make-directory spacemacs-cache-directory))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-432897> nil "/home/sharand/.emacs.d/core/core-load-paths.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2713
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sharand/.emacs.d/core/core-load-paths.el" "/home/sharand/.emacs.d/core/core-load-paths.el" nil nil)
  load("/home/sharand/.emacs.d/core/core-load-paths.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/home/sharand/.emacs.d/core/core-load-paths.el")
  (if (not (version<= spacemacs-emacs-min-version emacs-version)) (message (concat "Your version of Emacs (%s) is too old. " "Spacemacs requires Emacs version %s or above.") emacs-version spacemacs-emacs-min-version) (load-file (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name) "core/core-load-paths.el")) (require (quote core-spacemacs)) (spacemacs/init) (spacemacs/maybe-install-dotfile) (configuration-layer/sync) (spacemacs-buffer/display-info-box) (spacemacs/setup-startup-hook) (require (quote server)) (if (server-running-p) nil (server-start)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/sharand/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1302
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sharand/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/sharand/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/sharand/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266 \306=\203\307\310Q\202? \311=\204\307\312Q\202?\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202?\313\307\314\317#\203>\320\321\322!D\nB\323\202?\316\324\325\324\211#\210\324=\203e\326\327\330\307\331Q!\"\325\324\211#\210\324=\203d\210\203\247\332!\333\232\203\247\334!\211\335P\336!\203\201\211\202\214\336!\203\213\202\214\314\262\203\245\337\"\203\243\340\341#\210\342\343!\210\266\f?\205\264\314\325\344\324\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Please consider deleting the Stack Overflow version of this question.

Comment: @Dan I had one person suggest something, which I am going to try, after which I shall delete the SO counterpart.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala can you post the output of e.g. `ls -la /home/sharand/.emacs.d/.cache/` ? thanks.

Comment: @toogley I go all the way into `/home/sharand/.emacs.d/`, but there doesn't seem to be a `.cache` in the folder.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala that's because emacs has tried to create a `.cache` dir in this directory - but failed. The reason it failed is that there aren't sufficient permissions in that folder. Therefore you may try to manually create the folder: `mkdir /home/sharand/.emacs.d/.cache`

Comment: @toogley That is definitely the solution to this problem. If you put that down as an answer, I should be able to accept that answer.

Comment: Also, can you let me know how to change the writing permission without doing a `sudo emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

If writing permission is all you want, just run "chmod -R +w ~/.emacs.d", maybe sudo is needed.
But I think the best solution is to reinstall spacemacs without sudo or su previlege.

Comment: I `chmod`'ed  `.emacs.d` but I still get the same errors. What do you mean by reinstalling `spacemacs`? I've already reinstalled `emacs` a few times and have also worked `git clone`'ed the `spacemacs` `.emacs.d` directory, a few times.

Comment: before reinstalling, try the following: `sudo chown -R sharan.users .emacs.d; chmod -R u+rw .emacs.d`.  This should remove all issues concerning wrong ownership and wrong access permissions.