# Change the writing permissions of emacs

Tags: spacemacs, writing

I am currently trying to install spacemacs on my Arch Linux. I am following the standard installation instructions that have been put up [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#default-installation).

Now after cloning the `.emacs.d` from the `spacemacs` repository, whenever I open `emacs`, I get the error:

```
File error: Creating directory, Permission denied, /home/sharand/.emacs.d/. cache
```

After which, the suggestion on [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/cannot-install-spacemacs) question prompted me to create a `.cache` folder inside `.emacs.d`. But after this, I reopened `emacs` to get this error:

```
File error: Creating directory, Permission denied, /home/sharand/.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save
```

Now I am stuck in a cycle of creating folders and reopening `emacs`. I just want to know how to change the writing permissions of `emacs`. Invoking a `sudo emacs`, just makes it go to the default `emacs` and does not bring up `spacemacs` (does anyone know why this is the case?).

How would I go about making sure that I have writing permissions for `emacs`?

Comment: Are you able to install and use Emacs without any problems if we eliminate spacemacs from the list of potential problems?  Spacemacs is just a bunch of user-configurations and additional libraries on top of a base installation of Emacs.

Comment: @lawlist yes, `emacs` runs perfectly without the **configs** that `spacemacs` imposes.

Comment: What are the actual file permissions on those directories ? You can use 'find -ls' to see them all at once if I recall correctly.

Comment: @YoungFrog Could you please expand on that command?

Comment: 'find' is e.g. GNU find, a command line tool. `find -ls` will show all files/directories within current subdir, including their owner and permissions.